# MovieTexture Never Plays In Build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written a script to play OGG files as a MovieTexture, i've tried both embedded asset files and also from the web. The problem I'm having is that the videos play in debug move (When I hit the play button and test in the "Game" tab) but they never work when I build to an executable..

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
    public class VideoScreen : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string videoUrl;
        public bool autoPlay = true;
        public bool loop = true;
        public bool playAudio = true;
        public float opacity = 1.0f;

        private bool hasLoaded;
        private MovieTexture movieTexture;

        public void Start ()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(videoUrl))
            {
                return;
            }

            var data = new WWW(videoUrl);
            movieTexture = data.movie as MovieTexture;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            if (movieTexture.isReadyToPlay && !hasLoaded)
            {
                renderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/Unlit Transparent Color")) { mainTexture = movieTexture };
                audio.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;

                SetLoop(loop);

                if (autoPlay)
                {
                    Play();
                }

                hasLoaded = true;
            }

            var textureColor = renderer.material.color;
            textureColor.a = opacity;
            renderer.material.color = textureColor;
        }

        private void Play()
        {
            movieTexture.Stop();
            movieTexture.Play();

            if (playAudio)
            {
                audio.Stop();
                audio.Play();
            }
        }

        private void Pause()
        {
            movieTexture.Pause();
            if (playAudio)
            {
                audio.Pause();
            }
        }

        private void Stop()
        {
            movieTexture.Stop();
            if (playAudio)
            {
                audio.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void SetLoop(bool loopStatus)
        {
            movieTexture.loop = loopStatus;
            if (playAudio)
            {
                audio.loop = loopStatus;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the custom Transparent Diffuse shader I was using was causing the issue! Doh!!

```
renderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/Unlit Transparent Color")) { mainTexture = movieTexture };
```

now becomes

```
renderer.material.mainTexture = movieTexture;
```